# Lua: publish different sensors data simultaneously to topic

Tags: lua, mqtt, android-sensors, iot, esp8266

I am able to publish a data of different sensors (like temperature value and motion detection as zero or one) one at a time on a specific topic ( topic/temp/motion) using Lua code and subscribe in on my android app however i am not able to publish it simultaneously on same topic or sub-topic. Some ideas or examples would be great.
Below are some major bits of Lua code used.

```
orgID = "quickstart" -- IoT Foundation organization ID 
broker = "test.mosquitto.org"   --orgID..".messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com" -- IP or hostname of IoTF service
mqttPort = 1883 -- MQTT port (default 1883: non-secure)
userID = "" -- blank for quickstart
userPWD = "" -- blank for quickstart
macID = "18fe34e1b007" -- unique Device ID or Ethernet Mac Address <==== Modify this!
clientID = ":esp8266:18fe34e1b007" -- Client ID
count = 0 -- Test number of mqtt_do cycles
mqttState = 0 -- State control
topic = "topic/temp/motion"
led = 4
--gpio.mode(led,gpio.OUTPUT)
--dht sensor settings------------------------------
 pin = 1
-- PIR initialization section
pir = 2
x= 0 -- variable for sending motion detection information in "0 or 1"

function DHT_do()
status, temp, humi, temp_dec, humi_dec = dht.read(pin)
--gpio.write(led, gpio.LOW)
end


 function mqtt_do()
 count = count + 1 -- tmr.alarm counter
------------------------------------------- pir conditional code
if gpio.read(pir) ~= last_state then
        last_state = gpio.read(pir)
        if last_state == 1 then
        print("ON")
        x = 1
        gpio.write(led,gpio.HIGH)
        else
        print("OFF")
        x = 0
       gpio.write(led,gpio.LOW)

m:publish(topic,x, 0, 0,
 function(conn)
  print(x)
  print("temp_data:"..temp)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have included the code where you are trying to simultaneously publish the sensor values. Without that code it is impossible to help. BTW do you really mean 'simultaneous', i.e. In a single publish to a single topic?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the publish code to it, formatted as code,

Comment: -- to publish m:publish(topic,x,0,0, function(conn) -- Print confirmation of data published print(x) print("Sent message #"..count.." temp_data:"..temp) --gpio.write(led, gpio.HIGH) mqttState = 20 -- Finished publishing - go back to publish state. end) else print("Waiting..."..mqttState) mqttState = mqttState - 1 -- takes us gradually back to publish state to retry end end –